# VB net Error el proceso no puede tener acceso al archivo porque esta siendo usado en otro proceso

Tags: visual-studio, vb.net, visual

escribo para consultar sobre la excepción del método Delete de la clase File.

Al cambiar desde un OpenFileDialog una imagen desde un PictureBox por otra:

```
 Using file As New OpenFileDialog()
            file.Filter = "Image Files (*.jpg, *.jpeg, *.jpe, *.jfif, *.png) | *.jpg; *.jpeg; *.jpe; *.jfif; *.png"
            If file.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
                'si se actualiza la imagen guardamos la imagen anterior
                If (txtImagen.Text <> "") Then
                    'guardamos la imagen anterior para borrarla
                    imagenAnterior = DIRECTORIO & txtImagen.Text
                End If
                picImagen.Image = Image.FromFile(file.FileName)
                rutaOrigen = file.FileName
                'obtiene solo el nombre de la imagen
                txtImagen.Text = file.FileName.Substring(file.FileName.LastIndexOf("\") + 1)
            End If
        End Using
```

Quiero borrar la imagen anterior a la actualización del directorio de imágenes:

```
If (neg.Actualizar(objeto)) Then
                            MsgBox("Se ha actualizado correctamente", vbOKOnly + vbInformation, "Registro correcto")
                            File.Delete(imagenAnterior)
                            File.Copy(rutaOrigen, rutaDestino)
                            Me.Listar()
                        Else
                            MsgBox("No se ha podido actualizar", vbOKOnly + vbCritical, "Registro incorrecto")
                        End If
                    End If
```

Y la línea File.Delete(imagenAnterior) me lanza:

***El proceso no puede obtener acceso al archivo 'la ruta de la imagen anterior' porque está siendo utilizado en otro proceso.***

Desde ya gracias.

Comment: Alguien tiene abierta tu imagen.. estas seguro que nadie la tiene abierta?

Comment: No, es en mi pc y no la tengo abierta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El metodo Image.FromFile te esta bloquando la imagen.
Utiliza  Image.FromStream(stream)
Ejemplos:

```
picImagen.Image = ObtenerImagenDesdeArchivo(file.FileName)

Public Shared Function ObtenerImagenDesdeArchivo(path As String) As Image
    Using fs As New FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
        Dim img = Image.FromStream(fs)
        Return img
    End using
End Function
```

o

```
Public Shared Function ObtenerImagenDesdeArchivo(path As String) As Image
    Dim bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(path)
    Using ms As New MemoryStream(bytes)
        Dim img = Image.FromStream(ms)
        Return img
    End Using
End Function
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, si Image.FromFile hacia uso de la imagen.